# Google Recommendation AI Sample predict request in python from Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, function, cloud, recommendation-engine

I would like a help to create a sample request of predict API, my code is run on Google Cloud Functions.

I don't now how can I make the autentication and the request to call the predict recommendation like this example: https://cloud.google.com/retail/docs/predict#recommend

I alredy have created the service account and I have my cliend ID to test, but I need help to create a code that make autentication and call the API.

[My code example runing in Google Cloud Functions with Python, but its not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WHwA.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you could use token based service account impersonation as authorization method, anyways here is a google blog where they have made a predict request using google cloud functions with python -> https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/serving-predictions-evaluating-recommendations-ai

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31961288)

Comment: Thank You AlexK for the suggestion , I'll keep that in mind for my next answers.